# Universal asset-or-liability accounts in GnuCash

Tags: gnucash

Some accounts can sometimes change its type between asset and liability. For example, an accounts used for tracking a friend's debt, if each of us sometimes lends money to the other, and therefore the total amount is sometimes debit and sometimes credit. I want it to be correctly shown in the balance sheet and similar reports. The only idea I have is to change the type of the account from asset to liability and vise-versa and move the account between assets ans liabilities each time it changes the sign, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to move it anywhere. Leave it where it belongs most of the time. For example, if most of the time your friend ends up owing you money - you'll leave it in the assets section. During the periods where you end up owing money to your friend you'll just have an asset with a negative value. Also known as "liability", even though it will remain in the asset category in GnuCash. In your balance sheet it will negate the value of other assets bringing down the net worth exactly as any other liability would.

Alternatively you can use two accounts: accounts payable for what you owe to your friend and accounts receivable for what your friend owes you. The former is a liability, the latter is an asset. That would make your accounting a bit more complicated, but will reflect the situation more precisely.

Comment: When I say that I want it to be correctly shown in the balance sheet report, I mean not only the correct net worth, but also correct amounts for total assets and liabilities, without negative ones. So when I have a liability, it should increase total liabilities, not decrease assets. And having two accounts looks too complicated.

Comment: @anton-tsyganenko well.... In life you have to make compromises. You want both simple and precise, you can only have one of those.